# Jquery UI - setDate on datepicker after initialization

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, initialization, jquery-ui-datepicker

So I'm clear on how to manually change a date in the datepicker.  The problem comes in when I try to initialize the datepicker after the page has loaded and then try to change the date.

Here is a fiddle of what I'm referring to http://jsfiddle.net/nosfan1019/2VBLZ/2/.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="show">click to show</a>
<a href="#" class="set">Jan 9</a>
<br>
<div class="insert"></div>
```

​
JS

```
$('a.show').click(function() {
   $(".insert").datepicker();    
});

$('a.set').click(function() {
   $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate','01/09/13');       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second click event changes a div you don't seem to have (`$('#datepicker')`). 
If you change it to `$(".insert")`, it will work just fine.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2VBLZ/4/)**

```
$('a.show').click(function() {
    $(".insert").datepicker();    
});

$('a.set').click(function() {
    $(".insert").datepicker('setDate','01/09/2013');       
});
```

​

Comment: just realized that, damn my bad.